# Sortcode in Shortcode (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I would like to insert a shortcode in shortcode in WordPress.
It's my code, and I would like to insert to shortcode in place of "[SC]".

```
function offerbox($atts, $content = ''){    

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'text' => 'My text',
        'text2' => 'My another text',
        'button' => '[SC]'
    ), $atts)); 

    $html = '<div class="mydiv"><h2>' . $text . '</h2>' . $text2 . $button . '</div>';
    return $html;    
}

add_shortcode('offerbox', 'offerbox');
```

THX

Comment: I don't know if it would work properly, but maybe `do_shortcode($button)`?

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much.